# Trying to implement a Circular Enumeration in Scala

Tags: scala, enumeration

Below is the trait that I would like to use

```
trait CircularEnumeration extends Enumeration {

    class CircularVal extends Val {
      def next(): Value = {
        apply((id + 1) % values.size)
      }
    }

    protected override final def Value: CircularVal = new CircularVal;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    def nextValue(value: Value) = {
      //first way
      val nextIndex = values.toSeq.indexOf(value) + 1;
      val value_nomath = if (nextIndex >= values.size) {
        values.toSeq(0);
      }
      else {
        values.toSeq(nextIndex);
      }

      //second way
      val value_withmath = this((value.id + 1) % values.size);

      assert(value_nomath == value_withmath);

      value_withmath;
    }
}
```

You can see that I already have tried two ways, and both have failed.
In the first the usage would be something like this:
`MyEnumeration(index).next`
and this would return me the next value of this enumeration

In the second the usage would be like that:
`MyEnumeration.nextValue(MyEnumeration(index))`
and once again this would return the next value

but in both occasions I have issues of which type is which. Because inside the trait the `Value` is actually `CircularEnumeration.Value` while inside the class which has this trait tha `Value` is `MyEnumeration.Value`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I can get it to work with the following changes - modify the return type of nextValue:

```
def nextValue(value: Value): CircularEnumeration.this.Value = {
```

and the last line (returned value) to:

```
value_withmath.asInstanceOf[CircularEnumeration.this.Value]
```

Then, defining MyEnumeration as:

```
scala> object MyEnumeration extends CircularEnumeration {
     |     type MyEnumeration = Value
     |     val Zero, One, Two, Three, Four = Value
     | }
defined module MyEnumeration
```

we get:

```
scala> MyEnumeration.nextValue(MyEnumeration(3))
res0: MyEnumeration.Value = Four

scala> MyEnumeration.nextValue(MyEnumeration(4))
res1: MyEnumeration.Value = Zero
```

Comment: this made the difference: `CircularEnumeration.this.Value`. Thanks a lot, it works as expected :)